# How to efficiently compute large powers of 2?

Tags: c, performance, integer-arithmetic, exponentiation

I'm trying to calculate, for `0 < n ≤ 10⁹`, the value of

```
re=(2^n)%1000000007
```

I wrote this code:

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,re=1;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0; n>i; i++) re=(2*re)%1000000007;
    printf("%d",re);
}
```

When `n` is 10⁹, my code takes too long.

What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ArunAS Only if a decent description of the problem is given and the code in question is actually written by the OP. Take a look at [their help-center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mast yes, but I'm sure that the OP can access the full question since he is using an online judge. But your suggestion is indeed useful. When migrating to code review, there should be working code and good description

Comment: You can remove the `%1000000007` for the first 30 iterations.

Comment: @ArunAS Exactly. Migrate this as-is and the wrath of the community will descend on both the question and SO.

Comment: The best way to eliminate the error is to use a more efficient algorithm.  HTH.

Comment: Hint: what's `2^2`? `2^4`? `2^8`,`2^16`,`2^32`, ...?  And you know that `2^(4+1)` == `2^4 * 2^1`, so you can generalize that.  No need to iterate a billion times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in logarithmic time of `n` by computing power computation faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int kMod = 1000000007;

int Pow(int b, int p) {
    if (p == 0) return 1;
    int x = Pow(b, p >> 1);
    return ((((int64_t)x * x) % kMod) * (p & 1? b : 1)) % kMod;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //for(i=0; n>i; i++) re=(2*re)%1000000007;
    int re = Pow(2, n);
    printf("%d\n", re);
    return 0;
}
```

For example, 2<sup>5</sup> means computation of x = 2<sup>2</sup> and x * x * 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow binary exponentiation which will be something like

```
#define MOD 1000000007

long long fastExp(int b, int e) {
    long long r=1;
    while(e>0) {
       if(e&1) r=(r*b)%MOD;
       b=(b*b)%MOD;
       e/=2;
    }
    return r%MOD;
}
```

Call it like this `fastExp(2,n)`.

Well the complexity is pretty simple in that it does `log2(n)` operations so this will work better than your `O(n)` solution.

As an explanation to why your solution got TLE. The online judges available like that of `SPOJ` etc usually take 1 sec to do `10^8` loop operations. Here you do much more than that when you have `n=10^9` as input.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is smaller than `30`, the result is `1 << n`, otherwise you can calculate `1 << 30` and let your `for` loop start at `31`. You can also get rid of the expensive `%` operation if you check `if (re > 1000000007)` and subtract `1000000007` (because `re` is smaller than `1000000007` before multiplying it by `2`, it is smaller than `2*1000000007`, so subtracting `1000000007` is enough):

```
int foo(int n)
{
    if (n < 30) return 1 << n;
    int re = (1 << 30) % 1000000007;
    for(int i=31; n>i; i++)
    {
        re <<= 1;
        if (re > 1000000007) re -= 1000000007;
    }
    return re;
}
```

complete program: https://ideone.com/0FRcaf